# kali linux link speed

Tags: wifi, kali-linux

my Kali Linux WiFi link speed is showing 6mbps whereas in windows it shows 433mbps link speed. I am not running in a virtual environment, moreover if i do a speed test between my another laptop and this Kali Linux laptop i get a huge differences. The other laptop where windows is installed i get around 280mbps and in Kali Linux laptop I get only 20-25mbps. And yes I've a 300mbps fiber connection.

Comment: Do you have 2.4GHz and 5GHz WiFi networks?

Comment: I'm running it in 5GHZ. still the same slow speed. Moreover it's showing in the wifi setting that the link speed is 6mbps. But why if I'm using a windows it'll get the full speed.

Comment: Please check your `mb`, `Mb` and `MB` throughout. At least one of your `mb` should be `Mb` and there's a _significant_ difference in their number scales. Without you getting this right is is flatly impossibly to correlate the different speeds and bandwidths. Please also identify which connections are wired and which are wireless. For example, you can get a 433 Mb/s link speed on wireless with only a 9 Mb/s wired Internet connection. The link speed is about the link, not the throughput.

Comment: I understand but most important thing is that other laptop is getting full speed(running windows) and this kali linux laptop is not giving the full speed as windows, although both are connected to the same wifi.

Comment: At the very least you should add details about the hardware, and the drivers being used as well as details like signal strength, etc.